# Trying to write a code that will find the sum of the even numbers of the Fibonacci sequence?

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to write a program in Python that will find the sum of the even numbers of the numbers below 4,000,000 in the Fibonacci sequence. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but nothing will print. Thanks for any help.

```
def fib():  
    listx = []  
    for x in range(4000000):  
        if x == 0:  
            return 1
        elif x == 1:
            return 1
        else:
            listx.append(fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2))
            return listx

def evens(fib):
    y = 0
    for x in fib():
        if x % 2 == 0:
            y += x
        else:
            continue
        print (y)
```

Comment: You're not calling your functions. Unless you call them in your code, nothing will run at all.

Comment: `range(4000000)`? You're in for a (big) surprise...

Comment: Also, `if x == 1` and `if x == 0` can only be true once each for `range`. The other iterations are going to go into what I think is an attempt at recursion. Instead, use modulus `%` to check for odd/even.

Comment: @Evert, `range(4000000)` is *fine* with Python3 (the fact that it's `print(y)` rather than `print y` seems to indicate that's the version being used), that gives you an lazy iterator rather than a concrete collection. The real problem is then using that to construct a list rather than just processing the values.

Comment: Build your fibonacci sequence up from the bottom, otherwise you're calculating each value more than once

Comment: @paxdiablo my comment is about the idea of calculating the 3999999th Fibonacci number (or many below that).

Comment: @Evert, I stand corrected. Yes, the four millionth fibonacci number is vastly different to the highest fibonacci number less the four million. Have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @paxdiablo Actually, I started reading through the question and answers, and I notice that the question wording is  somewhat ambiguous, while the code suggests the calculating of ridiculously large Fibonacci numbers (`fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2)`). A few answers show use of  `< 4000000` limit (nowhere in the question's code), and then I remembered Euler problem number two. I see your answer now address this issue as well. So essentially, my comment could be seen as incorrect, for some value of incorrectness.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that uses a generator to keep memory usage to a minimum:

```
def fib_gen(up_to):
    n, m = 0, 1
    while n <= up_to:
        yield n
        n, m = m, n + m

total = 0
for f in fib_gen(4000000):
    if f % 2 == 0:
        total += f
```

Another option:

```
def fib_gen(up_to, filter):
    n, m = 0, 1
    while n <= up_to:
        if filter(n):
            yield n
        n, m = m, n + m

sum(fib_gen(4000000, lambda f: f % 2 == 0))  # sum of evens
sum(fib_gen(4000000, lambda f: f % 2))       # sum of odds
```

Comment: To clarify, OEIS says `0` *is* the first of the Fibonacci numbers

Answer (score 0):

First things first, there appears to be some contention between your requirements and the code you've delivered :-) The text of your question (presumably taken from an assignment, or Euler #2) requests the ...

> sum of the even numbers of the numbers below 4,000,000 in the Fibonacci sequence.

*Your* code is summing the even numbers from the first four million Fibonacci numbers which is *vastly* different. The four millionth Fibonacci number has, according to Binet's formula, north of 800,000 digits in it (as opposed to the seven digits in the highest one below four million).

So, assuming the text to be more correct than the code, you don't actually need to construct a list and then evaluate every item in it, that's rather wasteful on memory.

The Fibonacci numbers can be generated on the fly and then simply accumulated if they're even. It's also far more useful to be able to use an *arbitrary* method to accumulate the numbers, something like the following:

```
def sumFibWithCond(limit, callback):
    # Set up initial conditions.

    grandparent, parent, child = 0, 0, 1
    accum = 0

    # Loop until number is at or beyond limit.

    while child < limit:
        # Add any suitable number to the accumulator.

        accum = accum + callback(child)

        # Set up next Fibonacci cycle.

        grandparent, parent = parent, child
        child = grandparent + child

    # Return accumulator when done.

    return accum

def accumulateEvens(num):
    # Return even numbers as-is, zero for odd numbers.

    if num % 2 == 0:
        return num
    return 0

sumEvensBelowFourMillion = sumFibWithCond(4000000, accumulateEvens)
```

Of special note is the initial conditions. The numbers are initialised to `0, 0, 1` since we want to ensure we check *every* Fibonacci number (in `child`) for the accumulating condition. This means the initial value of `child` should be one assuming, as per the question, that's the first number you want.

This doesn't make any difference in the current scenario since one is not even but, were you to change the accumulating condition to "odd numbers" (or any other condition that allowed for one), it *would* make a difference.

And, if you'd prefer to subscribe to the Fibonacci sequence starting with zero, the starting values should be `0, 1, 0` instead.

Comment: Even better, you don't need to divide each one by 2; you can simply return every 3rd number: 1, 1, **2**, 3, 5, **8**, 13, 21, **34**, ...

Comment: @chepner, that's fine for the very specific case but the code as it stands now is far more adaptable, meaning tricks such as every third number can't be relied upon.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help you.

```
def sumOfEvenFibs():
    # a,b,c in the Fibonacci sequence
    a = 1
    b = 1
    result = 0
    while b < 4000000:
        if b % 2 == 0:
            result += b
        c = a + b
        a = b 
        b = c
    return result
```

Comment: This is summing the odd numbers.